# How to count NULLS in one columns corresponding to every unique element in another column through MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in MYSQL table - something like this:

```
Col. 1   |  Col. 2
value1   |  yes
value1   |  yes
value2   |  NULL
value2   |  NULL
value3   |  yes 
value3   |  NULL
value4   |  yes
value5   |  NULL
```

I want to find how many unique values in column 1 have atleast one NULL in column 2.

So, in this case the final answer would be 3 (value2, value3 and value5). There are no NULLS corresponding to value1 and value4.

Is there a way to write MYSQL query for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct col1)
from t
where col2 is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col1)
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE Col2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use subquery

```
select * from table where col1 in (
 select col1  From table where col2 = null)
```